# Sudo directive in /etc/sudoers.d doesn't work (but it's fine if it's in /etc/sudoers)

Tags: sudo, ubuntu-18.04

I wish to add a file to the `/etc/sudoers.d` folder that includes a directive to allow `www-data` to run one specific script with no root password.

The directive is

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh
```

If I `visudo` and add it to `/etc/sudoers`, there is no problem.

If I put that line in a file and copy it to `/etc/sudoers.d`, then `visudo`, it tells me that the file has a 'syntax error near line 1'.

Is there something else I need to put in the file, or something else I need to do to make it work?

I am running Ubuntu 18.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want the script to run at any interval, You can go for cron..

Comment: I do not want the script to run at an interval, only as and when called from the webapp (which is likely to be once or so a year)

Comment: Just in case, file without newline at the end is incorrect UNIX text file.

Comment: @Hauleth - as per the answer (which I can't accept until tomorrow), that was indeed the problem!

Comment: visudo also has the -f flag you can use to edit a specific file. That way you can be sure that your files are always correct.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found out the problem - for files in /etc/sudoers.d, the file must not end at the directive, but on a new line. This is most easily shown with `cat -A`.

Invalid file:

```
root@server:/etc/sudoers.d# cat -A /etc/sudoers.d/testfile
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.shroot@server:/etc/sudoers.d#
```

Valid file:

```
root@server:/etc/sudoers.d# cat -A /etc/sudoers.d/testfile
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh$
root@server:/etc/sudoers.d#
```

Comment: i.e., [the file must be a **valid text file**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446237/70524). If your file doesn't end in a newline, it's not a valid text file.

Comment: I had no idea that no newline meant it was an invalid text file - I just pasted the line into a file and saved it!

Comment: Did you use nano or Vim?

Comment: Neither, the file exists within my project and I used the IDE editor (PHPStorm) to create the file, which was then deployed to the staging server and copied to `/etc/sudoers.d` for testing

Comment: Blame the lame editor then. Any decent Unix editor will add that final newline if it's missing.

Comment: It's not a Unix editor, but I will still send feedback!

Answer (score 1):

According to the `/etc/sudoers.d/README`, the filename should not have the `.` symbol in its name. This was the issue for me -- I have used the `.conf` extension.

```
# This will cause sudo to read and parse any files in the /etc/sudoers.d 
# directory that do not end in '~' or contain a '.' character.
```

Files should also be in 0440 mode.

Thus, my solution was to rename the file:

```
sudo mv /etc/sudoers.d/50-jenkins.conf /etc/sudoers.d/50-jenkins
sudo ls -al /etc/sudoers.d/
```

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 окт 10 17:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 157 root root 12288 окт 10 17:44 ..
-r--r-----   1 root root   268 окт 10 17:44 50-jenkins
-r--r-----   1 root root   958 мар 30  2016 README
```